# mongoDB version - 3.4.10 | How to create read only user

Tags: mongodb

I did below step's but when i login to new created i am able to Add/Edit/Delete `data`

**Step - I : Changed  `/etc/mongod.conf` and add below `configuration`** 
`security:on`
`auth` = `true`

**Step - II : restart mongo** 
`sudo service mongod restart`

**Step - III : Create new `user`**

```
var user = {
  "user" : "abc123",
  "pwd" : "abc123",
  roles : [
      {
          "role" : "readAnyDatabase",
          "db" : "admin"
      }
  ]
}
db.createUser(user);
```

**Step IV : connect with new user** 
`mongo abc123 -u abc123 -p`

Is am doing anything wrong ? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: When i try to log-in with new created ie. abc123 then i am able to add/edit/delete data. new user got all access. 
i want to create user with only read only access ...